#  500 Internal Server Error in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working in ASP.NET MVC. I am using partial views, but when I clicked on particular link I got the following error.

> 500 Internal Server Error

How can this error be fixed?

Comment: Turn off friendly error messages in your browser, and allow debugging in your application, and then tell us the error so that we can help you better.

Comment: The advice here on getting your server to return you more detailed error information may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5385714/12484

Answer (score 7, accepted):

500 Server error means that a script has thrown an error, this is not a broken link (aka a 404 error).

If you are using Internet Explorer, go to `tools > options > advanced` and unselect `friendly http errors`, this will give you a more comprehensive description of the error so you can debug the script, or contact the relevant people to debug it.

Answer (score 64):

To check what causes Internal Server 500 Error under ASP MVC you can also run your app in debug mode and check  property AllErrors.
 The property is an array of Exception type elements.

To do this open `Global.asax.cs` (C#) and in the body of class `MvcApplication` put method `Application_EndRequest`:

```
protected void Application_EndRequest()
{   //here breakpoint
    // under debug mode you can find the exceptions at code: this.Context.AllErrors
}
```

Then set breakpoint and check contents of the array: `this.Context.AllErrors`

It helped me to resolve what exception was thrown and optionally to see the stacktrace.

Comment: Great answer! I've tried checking the network tab but it never gave me a detailed error. It just stated that it failed to load the resource. This solution pointed out there was a issue with my viewmodel's constructor. Thanks!

Comment: what if I get `this.Context.AllErrors` to null?

Comment: i tried this solution but i got this.Context.AllErrors = null... so after digging it more i found out that in my model which i have bound to form i have decorated one of integer property with "[MaxLength(6, ErrorMessage = "Pincode should be valid.")]" after removing this it worked fine for me.

Comment: where i can find : `this.Context.AllErrors` ?

Answer (score 5):

I got more details of the error from windows event viewer(Run>eventvwr.msc>Windows Logs>Application). Check the warnings/errors recorded from w3wp.exe

In my case the reason was missing dlls. Hope this helps

Comment: upgrading from .net core to .net 5.0 was throwing 500 internal error on server & clueless after a days work, the page was coming blank & no detailed information even after setting customErrors to true in web.config, with information in the Application able to figure out that there is a know issue https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/knowledge-base/binaryformatter-exception-after-upgrade-to-net5

Answer (score 2):

Though a little late, the Anti-Forgery token blocks the request as a security measure.

Removing all those anti-forgery tags in .cshtml and controller, removed the error for me.

Though if you want to keep those tokens successfully use this link:-
http://iamdotnetcrazy.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-to-solve-anti-forgery-token-could.html