# The resource cannot be found. When I deploy ASP.net on IIS7

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I try to put my ASP.net website on IIS7, by setting the folders and aspx-files in wwwroot. When I try to access http://10.32.0.235/Integ/Overzichtscherm.aspx,

I get this error: `The resource cannot be found.`

Can someone help me, please. Thank you in advance.

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error/5385884#5385884

Comment: @Tassisto Do you have access to IIS7 ?

Comment: I've had weird stuff like this, typically you need to ensure your handler mappings are OK

Comment: Please edit this question to add the information it is lacking.

Comment: The problem is fixed just by restoring the server, I really don't know what's the cause & solution for this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your IIS would be up and running correctly you would get a 404 message rather than the message you get now if some files would be missing etc..

Make sure in the IIS admin that your "website" is up and running and listening on the correct port and that the IIS service is running with correct ASP .NET settings. [Here](http://www.bipinjoshi.net/articles/df885319-19cc-47b8-8808-6ed462db1de5.aspx) is a good tutorial for setting up IIS7

Comment: If you run through the tutorial you might find a configuration that is wrong. Are you testing this on your local machine or is it a remote machine? How did you deploy the code to the www directory etc

Comment: I will restore the server and if I experience errors I will come back with more info

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting ASP.NET Version for the VD and check settings to make sure it is properly configured..

Comment: I'm not familiar with windows server. can you show me how I can achieve that? and what do you mean with VD?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and it turns out that when I setup the web server I  inadvertently forgot to select ASP.NET 4.5 under the webs server. 
Selecting this will automatically select the .NET Extensions 4.5. Once selecting these and doing an IIS Reset all was well and the site loaded properly.