# Defined client cache seems to get ignored

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but despite of everything I've tried, I don't seem to be able to get the clients to cache my static resources.

In my web.config, I've added the following entry:

```
  <staticContent>
    <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="30.00:00:00" />
  </staticContent>
```

According to the documentation, this should send a response header to the client browser to let it know we want to keep static content cached for 30 days.

If I use fiddler to see what the client is receiving, it looks like my web.config addition gets ignored completely.

Below is what fiddler is reporting:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Date: Mon, 05 Dec 2011 14:09:44 GMT
Expires: -1
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

I don't have any headers in IIS overriding this so I'm not sure what is it that I am missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I cracked this but it took a while. You're trying to force 304s from the server (no change). It differs with IIS versions.

It's best achieved by having all you're static content in one directory 
(e.g. `content` so you'd have `/content/css` `/content/js etc`)

Then you just have to ensure everything under that directory doesn't expire for, say, 30 days.

**IIS7**

Much easier. Easiest way - add a `web.config` to the content directory referred to above. This `web.config` will have just the expires directive:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <clientCache
            cacheControlMaxAge="30.00:00:00" 
            cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

**IIS6**

You'll need to manipulate the metabase. It's not XML in IIS6, follow the instructions here: [IIS6 ETags metabase commands](http://forums.iis.net/t/1067723.aspx)

We used both the above and simple viewing of firebug shows 304s coming through.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your help. I do get the 304s as you point out above but adding the web.config in the content folder didn't make a bit of a difference. I've tried adding the new web.config to the /Content folder and ended up getting 500 errors (_there is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed_). I've also moved it to the folder where the resource is: /Content/css and the css file was now retrieved successfully but with the no-cache header again.

Comment: Looks like this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error routing maybe....