# error: the details of the application error from being viewed remotely

Tags: asp.net, sql, web-config, connection-string

I have 2 login pages: Login.aspx-for customer login and xlogin.aspx for admin login
i just uploaded my project to the server and all application pages works great
but when i log in the admin xlogin.aspx i'm being forwarded to the admin.aspx page - but i get this error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Runtime Error
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>


Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
    <add name="PROJEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/PROJModel.csdl|res://*/PROJModel.ssdl|res://*/PROJModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=000.000.0.00;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;User ID=MYUSERNAME;Password=MYPASS;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="720" slidingExpiration="true" defaultUrl="~/Gateway.ashx"/>
    </authentication>

    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <pages enableEventValidation="false" viewStateEncryptionMode="Never"></pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization>
          <converters>
            <add type="PROJ.Presentation.Common.DateTimeConverter" name="DateTimeJavaScriptConverter"/>
          </converters>
        </jsonSerialization>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You need to look at the error.  Something is going wrong on that page.  Turn custom errors on and take a look at the error message.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Dear olga is clear what the message says. Turn off the custom errors to see the details about this error for fix it, and then you close them back. So add mode="off" as:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Relative answer:
[Deploying website: 500 - Internal server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error/5385884#5385884)

By the way: The error message declare that the web.config is not the one you type it here. Maybe you have forget to upload your web.config ? And remember to close the debug flag on the web.config that you use for online pages.

Answer (score 1):

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

Answer (score 1):

This can be the message you receive even when custom errors is turned off in web.config file.  It can mean you have run out of free space on the drive that hosts the application.  Clean your log files if you have no other space to gain on the drive.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I got this message because there's a special char (&) in my connectionstring, remove it then everything's good.

Cheers