# 404 error when trying to download file on Windows Server 2003

Tags: sqlite, download, http-status-code-404, windows-server-2003

I'm trying to put a .sqlite database file on my server so users can download it (ultimately it is going to be a replacement/update for a database that ships with an iOS app - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150196/updating-sqlite-database-without-xml/16390498?noredirect=1#16390498) for more background).  On our server, we have a "download" folder that is currently being used to allow users to successfully download .mde database files.  I tried putting my .sqlite file in that same download folder (and just changing it so I'm pointing to the .sqlite database instead of the .mde database), but that doesn't work - I get a http status code 404.

For example, if I just open a new Internet Explorer or Firefox window and type the location of the .mde in the address bar, I get a prompt asking if I want to save the file or choose to open it with an application from a list.  If I type the location to the .sqlite file, I don't get any download prompt, I just get redirected to an error screen showing the 404 code (and I've verified that I typed the filename and directory for the .sqlite file correctly about 100 times).

Is there anything more I need to do to allow my .sqlite file to be downloaded (like "register" that particular file or extension somehow)?

I'm really unfamiliar with all this server side stuff, so if something is unclear I apologize, and I'll try to provide any other information that may be helpful if I can.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download it like `right click --> 'save link as'` or just open `site.com/folder`, so it will list all the files in that folder .. let me know if you see your .sqlite file there.

Also, there must be another explanation of why you receive the 404 error code since it means:

```
The 404 or Not Found error message is a HTTP standard response code indicating that the client was able to communicate with the server, but the server could not find what was requested.
```

Are you sure that you're uploading it to the correct folder ?

UPDATE: Please feel free to check this out: [error: the details of the application error from being viewed remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783651/error-the-details-of-the-application-error-from-being-viewed-remotely)

Also, try this solution:

Copy and paste the text of the error into the web.config file so that the file only has this in it.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web> </configuration>
```

Rename the Web.Config file in the root of the application folder to web.config (case sensitive). My application is in the public/abc folder so I would put the web.config file there. It does not need to go into the /public folder or the / folder.

Comment: When I do `save target as` it opens a browse so I can select where to save it, but when I click `Save` I just get a message `myDB couldn't be downloaded`.  No other error message (just options to `retry`, `cancel`, or `view downloads`).  When I try just the folder, I get another error screen saying `Server Error in '/' Application`.  It goes on to say that `The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons).`

Comment: Updated my first answer above.

Comment: Hm, I'd only have a web.config file if this was a Web Application, right?  I don't have an application running this at all - it's just a file I'm trying to put on my server to make available for download.