# Sitecore azure re-deployment

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-azure

I am using site-core azure for deployment.
I have clean-up the deployment using the link below:
https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/771717

after that when i am trying to deploy again, its throwing below error:

> Execute package failed System.ApplicationException:
>   AdvaiyaWebSiteTestScusCe01Role01SSc437Staging [S] Execute package
>   failed ---> System.ApplicationException: Execute package is failed
>   ---> System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Object '/e44991be_f499_4234_a3a7_de70f8a3bcf7/6qjthylyeqgvlu+u0v4xxedj_286.rem'
>   has been disconnected or does not exist at the server. Server stack
>   trace: at System.IO.FileStream.get_CanRead() at
>   MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOLocalFileBlock.CheckFileAccessParameter(Stream
>   stream, FileAccess access) at

How to resolve?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this error using both Sitecore Azure module and Visual Studio, where Azure .NET SDK 2.5 were used. Nevertheless, I have not seen it with SDK 2.4 or 2.6.

Since you cannot use the other SDK version with Sitecore Azure module, the only thing you can try is, to run a deployment again.

Otherwise, use the latest Azure .NET SDK with Visual Studio:
https://github.com/olegburov/sitecore-azure-content/blob/master/articles/how-to-deploy-sitecore-80-solution-to-microsoft-azure-web-app-using-visual-studio.md

Comment: I have followed the setps mentined in the link above. Now I am getting the error after successful publish to Azure. 'Could not resolve type name: Sitecore.Azure.Startup.Pipelines.Loader.RebuildSearchIndex, Sitecore.Azure.Startup;

Comment: The reason of this issue is because you have published the '\App_Config\Include\Sitecore.Azure.Startup.config' file, but missed the \bin\Sitecore.Azure.Startup.dll' one. You can use Visual Studio Online Extension in the Azure Portal to see the file system of you Web App.

Comment: Ok, from where i can get this file?

Comment: It comes with Sitecore.Azure.Setup NuGet Package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sitecore.Azure.Setup

Comment: Ok, i got it. Getting below error now: An application error occurred on the server......"Server Error in '/' Application",,,,,,The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Comment: This is a general ASP.NET configuration thing. See here for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783651/error-the-details-of-the-application-error-from-being-viewed-remotely

Comment: Is the session database must to be created? I am unable to create session database on Azure.....multiple error are there in creating script or generating database in different ways as below:
"Reference to database and/or server name in 'temp.dbo.Application' is not supported in this version of SQL Server."...................and the website is giving below error now  "Invalid object name 'Applications'.

Answer (score 0):

To export Sitecore Session database as *.bacpac file please refer to the following article: https://github.com/olegburov/sitecore-azure-content/blob/master/articles/how-to-deploy-sitecore-databases-to-azure-sql-database.md

Comment: I tried the same its giving error "Exporting database failed", Extracting schema failed, inside export data tier application. Ex. of details error messages is: [information_schema].[tables].[table_schema]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[CreateTables]: Procedure: [dbo].[CreateTables] has an unresolved reference to object [tempdb]. There are multiple errors like this.

Comment: It gives error "Synonym 'Applications' refers to an invalid object, while executing GetApplicationId SProc of session database.

Comment: All these configuration issues are resolved now its throwing SQL server exception 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'Items'.