# Getting error after deploying an application

Tags: c#, jquery, iis, model-view-controller, hosting

I have deployed a project in a server. I have done all required configurations for IIS. I need my application to be hosted inside a site which is working perfectly fine i.e (abcxyz.com). If I am hosting my new application outside the folder then it is working perfectly fine. When I am trying to host inside the folder it is not working and giving the below error.

> An application error occurred on the server.
>   The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons).
>    It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Comment: This isn't the real error. See the accepted answer on the link to turn custom errors off. You can then see the real error and troubleshoot that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783651/error-the-details-of-the-application-error-from-being-viewed-remotely

Comment: Probably your virtual directory (folder) isn’t configured as an Application in IIS ... in IIS Manager, right click on the folder and select covert to application ...

Comment: No i have already converted the desired folder to application..anyway i got the error logged in to log file..now probably it ll get solved very soon...