# Could not load assembly WebPages.Deployment version 2 at host?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis, hosting, .net-assembly

I have a ASP.NET MVC 2 website (VS2010) that I have upgraded to ASP.NET MVC 3 (VS2012) and this works fin on local IIS7 but when publishing it I get this exception on host :

```
 Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

After some seartch I found [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx) that states that I should set CopyLocal on some of the references(inlcuding the System.Web.WebPages) and also use the publish tool in VS2012, but this generated the following exception?

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

And I can´t find any Deployment dll to set copyLocal?

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have a read of http://joel.net/getting-asp.net-mvc-3-working-on-discountasp.net

You need to add a reference to System.Web.WebPages.Deployment and set that also to CopyLocal.

Comment: It's a shame but this link now does not work anymore (404 error); and takes you to the home page of that website.