# Ajax toolkit not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

On my developer environment ajax toolkit is working good. Rendering textbox as sliders. All good. But when I'm putting it into the web host, it's not working. The textboxes are left as well and enormous error on console (chrome and firfox)

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < ScriptResource.axd:1
Uncaught Sys.ArgumentUndefinedException: Sys.ArgumentUndefinedException: Value cannot be undefined.
Parameter name: baseType ScriptResource.axd:847
Uncaught Sys.ArgumentUndefinedException: Sys.ArgumentUndefinedException: Value cannot be undefined.
Parameter name: type ScriptResource.axd:847
2
Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500 ScriptResource.axd:847
```

I tried reinstalling ajaxtoolkitfrom packagemaneger but didn't work. Still same problem.

Any Ideas?

Comment: The erorr code is 500, that means your c# code crashed on server side.

Comment: The error code 500 is too general, you need to read on the server log the real error to been able to get help ! And one similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error/5385884#5385884

Comment: but why it's that it's working good on my development server?

Comment: and what about the other errors

Answer (score 2):

It's the just browser cache. Clearing those resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error too. For me, it turned out that I had used the wrong Script manager.

On the page which uses the Ajax control, I had a standard `<asp:ScriptManager>`. My control (an `<ajaxToolkit:ComboBox>`) did not work. When I used a `<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>` instead, it started behaving as expected.

I don't know if this will solve the error in all cases, but it is one more thing to check for.

Answer (score 0):

The baseType argument in ScriptResource.axd @ line 847 is undefined. Same is true for the type parameter.

Here's what I would do. Try installing your bits on another machine, perhaps in your office right next to your development machine. The error indicates some resource IS NOT installed. Trying to repro a working copy of you setup, on a clean machine is the first step.

After you've done that, post an update here...

Comment: okay. I'll go that. I don't have a extra machine. It's gonna take a while.

Comment: It was just the browser cache. Clear the cache. All fine. Thanks for your replies.