# Server Error in '/' Application only on aspx pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I have a weird error, I uploaded my website on a new server and i can't access my aspx pages where i am getting `Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found` but in the same directory i put html page and an image where both where i was able to view both

Comment: the error is the usual Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Comment: It's giving 404 error means asp.net in unable to find the page... can you share screenshot.

Comment: i am telling you it is the normal 404 page like this one http://www.tayyar.org/tayyar/NewsDetailserwerewr.aspx

Comment: This is a general error, find the real reason. Look at that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error/5385884#5385884

Comment: On the site you give this is the "normal" 404 error not found http://www.tayyar.org/tayyar/newsdetailserwerewr