# Runtime error when uploading a project

Tags: asp.net, runtime-error, umbraco, blogengine.net

I'm having a runtime error when i upload BlogEngine to my website (or Umbraco CMS to another domain). It is the same error as I usually get:

> Runtime Error Description: An application error occurred on the
>   server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent
>   the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for
>   security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on
>   the local server machine.
>
> Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be
>   viewable on remote machines, please create a tag within a "web.config"
>   configuration file located in the root directory of the current web
>   application. This tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to
>   "Off".

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration> <system.web> <customErrors mode="Off"/> 
     </system.web> </configuration>
```

> Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a
>   custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the
>   application's  configuration tag to point to a custom
>   error page URL.

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration> <system.web> <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"  
    defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/> </system.web> </configuration>
```

So what I would go and do is that I will check if the domain settings are set to ASP.NET 2.0 and it is, so what is wrong? I upload a project that is successful build on my own computer, but when uploaded - it's another story! What's wrong, and how can i fix it?

Comment: We can't see the actual error. What's the error in `IIS` logs or from the Event Viewer? Or browse locally on remote machine to see error, or turn off `customErrors` (not recommended).

Comment: Please take a look to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error/5385884#5385884

Comment: When I run it in ISS (localhost) it tells me it is a http-error 500.19:
   64:   </system.serviceModel>
   65:   <system.web.extensions>
   66:     <scripting>

If I run it through VisualWebDeveloper, there are no problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since version 2.5 BlogEngine.Net has required .net 4.0.  Since you are running the application  with .net 2.0/3.5 it will not load.  You should be able to change this by altering the application pool your site is in.

[Blog Engine Road Map](http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/page/road-map.aspx)

Comment: In the controlpanel @ my host (surftown.dk), the only offer I have is to set the ASP.NET version to "1.1.4327" or "2.0.50727" (which i'm using)! So that means they are not able to host it?? Strange...

Comment: On our servers .net 4 is showing as 4.0.30319 so it appears your host does not support .net 4.  I believe you are going to have to switch hosting environments.

Comment: YES, leemicw...I found out that it was not an option automatically. I contacted them, and they told me I should tell them if I wanted a Windows2008 solution that support .net 4.0.