# httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" causes 500 - Internal server error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, asp.net-4.5

I am converting mvc4 project, 4.0 to 4.5

I need to add the folowing line to system.web in web config, but when I do, I get 500 - Internal server error

```
 <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
```

Comment: Did you change the target in your project build settings to 4.5?

Comment: Did you change the app pool to 4.5 in IIS manager?

Comment: Must be your code then. Try to get something more concrete than a 500..that is really vague. Get to an inner exception and post it.

Comment: This is a general message, find the actual reason. Check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error/5385884#5385884

Comment: @Aristos did that, but it does not display the error.

Comment: @user1615362 Is your pool 4.5 ? meaning, that you must also have update your net from 4.0 to 4.5, not only the project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out that I was trying to add the httpRuntime, when it already existed at the end of the system.web. 
To resolve the issue I did a merge:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="1200" targetFramework="4.5"/>
```