# 500 (Internal Server Error) in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http

i am working with `MVC4`. Receiving `500 (Internal Server Error)` error while requesting for bulk amount of data. i think it is because of heavy amount of data. how to fix it ???
Error description is :

```
'Error during serialization or de-serialization using JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the MaxJasonLength property.'
```

i have tried this in web.config:

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="1500000000000" />
```

but still no difference!

Comment: well what is the problem? what is causing 500?

Comment: as i mentioned above, its due to bulk. i want to fix it!

Comment: Check the stacktrace /innerexception to see what is causing the error

Comment: how are you processing the bulk? wtf man.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error) to find out the actual, underlying error.

Comment: You are going to need to actually provide the error if you want an answer.  As it stands, there is no way possible for anyone to assist you as a 500 error could be caused by literally any coding error.

Comment: try
        {
            xhrRequest.send(data);
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
it just move me to that method! @Tommy

Comment: sending list of objects from controller!!! and it shows error while returning that list back to view! @DarthVader

Comment: Please, **[edit]** your Question to add details. Down and close votes are casted based on the Q, not Comments.

Comment: u understand english? what is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, there are a few places that you need to update the value to override the default maximum lengths.  What you have posted as your attempt is not the correct place however.

First, update your web.config with the following block

```
<system.web.extensions>
       <scripting>
           <webServices>
               <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
           </webServices>
       </scripting>
   </system.web.extensions>
```

If you are still having issues (as I think this setting is not honored in a controller for some reason on MVC4), you can try the following when you are actually serializing the data.

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;

var jsonData = new { key = Records };
var result = new ContentResult{
    Content = serializer.Serialize(jsonData),
    ContentType = "application/json"
};
return result;
```

Comment: if i want to set any key , how to set it then ? @Tommy

Comment: @user3131402  I don't know what you mean by that comment.

Comment: I am using this statement   return Json(new { key = Records }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet );
where Records is list of objects. now according to your code, how to set that key ? @tommy

Comment: @user3131402 - look at the above edits

Answer (score -1):

In MVC 4 you have the async controller options. I suppose you are having a grid with huge sets of data. This kind of scenario used to work well in classic ASP. There developers will periodically flush the response after certain number of rows are generated. But in ASP.Net webforms and ASP.Net MVC you have to handle them differently. Async controller will give some good performance here. I referred msdn article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598(v=vs.100).aspx

```
    public void IndexAsync(string input)
    {
        List<Sample> test = new List<Sample>();
        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();
        //You can replace this GetHashCode with different webservice call or some other delaying task
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            test.Add(new Sample {SampleID=i,Name="Meow" });
        }
        AsyncManager.Parameters["inp"] = test;
        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
    }
    public  ActionResult IndexCompleted(IList<Sample> inp)
    {
       return View(inp);
    }
```

Comment: i have identified my problem. kindly review the question! @thanigainathan