# ASP.NET - How to Deploy in VS Express 2013 for Web?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, web-deployment

Ok, so I have been creating the same project like 15 times now, have created it in 2008, with the .NET Framework of 3.5 (New Web Site, New Web Project, and OMG, like all different ways).  Have deployed this, however, when I try to load it in localhost, (because I am building these Applications directly from within the Server), I get all kinds of errors.  Than I get an error that says, needs to use .NET Framework 4.0.

So, in order to use .NET Framework 4.0, I need to have atleast VS Express 2012, so I get VS Express 2013 and Rebuild the Application again, but this time, I do not see option for Web Application in this software, I see this:  ASP.NET Web Forms Application, there is an option for ASP.NET Empty Web Application and I have done both of these damn things!  Not sure which one is supposed to actually work.

For the Forms Application, I don't see any option to Publish it, only to Build!

In any case, how the hell are you supposed to transfer your VS 2013 .NET Framework 4.0 Web Application so that it will work on the actual SERVER (Public URL)?  How to do this is baffling the hell out of me.  No matter what I do I get errors, I can't even get VS Express 2013 to even work when building it, since it gives me 500 error or Page Not Found 404 Error.  Atleast with VS Express 2008, I got some errors on the page that told me that the aspx file actually trying to load in the browser.

How do you deploy this project in VS Express 2013 for Web Exactly?  What are the steps to do this from within the actual SERVER itself?  Also, I just want a simple web application that ties into an existing site (that will use an iframe on an existing page) that uses a Web Service.  What application to choose to use?  What type should be created?  There are so many and they all seem the same to me!  I believe the type should be ASP.NET Web Forms Application, but this doesn't seem to want to be published after working in it.  It only Builds, and than I don't know how to put it on the Server after that.  I have it in a folder on the server, but it loads nothing when I go to that page.  It can not find the Default.aspx file.  ARGGG!  I am pulling out my hair now!

Perhaps there is a URL somewhere online that explains how to do this? From within the localhost itself?

Comment: The publishing option for ASP.NET Web Applications basically is just a nice wizard that moves the result of a build to a path you specify. Manually building and copying the appropriate directories to where IIS is looking also does the trick.

Comment: There is no magic in a deploy.  All it's doing is copying files to another location.  This is something you can do yourself.  It's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do through all your complaints, since it doesn't seem to me like you actually even need visual studio or a web application.  It sounds like you just need an html page that has an iframe on it.

Comment: @ErikTheViking - I can generate an HTML page anywhere, that's not the problem, but the iframe's SRC will be a path/url to a `Default.aspx` file that uses `Default.aspx.cs` with code that hooks into a Web Service and outputs the information from it via SOAP on the page (within an iframe, this is to say that it will be in an iframe), not that it matters at all.  I still need to create the Web Application and have it hooked up into IIS properly, which I don't know how to do.

Comment: @CodeCaster - How to you Manually Build and copy the directories to where IIS is looking?  IIS is outputting the `c:/inetpub/Website_new` directory when I go to `http://localhost`, and this works fine, but when I build and copy the files to:  `c:/inetpub/Website_new/test` directory and than browse to `http://localhost/test/Default.aspx` it gives me a 500 Internal Server Error!  So there is a Server Problem and is not loading the page at all.  Does something need to be done within the IIS Manager?  And where is this `wizard` you speak of?

Comment: Probably you have to create an Application from your `test` directory. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error) to find out the actual error.

Comment: Also, in the Settings of the Application, there are a few options to build to.  The option that was selected by default was `DLL`, but there were 2 more... 1 was something about a `Library` and I think the other was a `Windows Application`, no sure.  But none of them sounded right for a Website, so just left it at the default `DLL` option, is this right?

Comment: @CodeCaster - Thanks, that was it, needed to create the Application in IIS, and also, needed to change a few settings in the web.config files for both, the main site and the application on the site.

Comment: Consider the fact that Microsoft stops the Express edition (VS2017 Express is the last), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express This question should be closed in certain ways (accepting an answer below, posting your own answer, or simply deleting it).

Answer (score 0):

You will see publish option if you Select your Website in the solution explorer and

1) right click it

Or

2) Go to Build menu on the top

Regarding project types:
-> If you select New Project -> You get option for creating a Web Application
-> If you select New Website -> You get option to create Website

You might want to upload some screenshots of your VS environment / errors to show what problem you are exactly facing.

Comment: There is no Publish Option in the Menu at the top, nor is there one when I right click on the Website in the solution explorer, and there is no `Build` Menu, there is a `Debug` Menu, and `Build` is a Sub Menu of that.  But that is it.  I do not see Publish anywhere!

Comment: I do not have access to this right now, but will be back tomorrow with Screenshots for you!

Comment: Which one should I create for what I need?  `New Project -> Web Application`? or `New Website -> create Website`?  And I do not remember seeing `Web Application`, there is only `Empty Web Application` which I assume you are speaking about...

Comment: Yes, it will be Empty Website or Empty Web Application options depending on what route you select first. What to use, depends on your requirement. Check the difference between the two here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I got it working through IIS, as it wasn't set up to be a Web Application, set it up and now it works.  Had to do a bunch of other edits to both web.config files for the main site and for the other site, but is working perfect now!  Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Web Application Project in Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web. After creating the Web Application you can Publish it to the web but you need to create a profile. You can also publish to Windows Azure.

Some steps are shown in this [article](http://hodentek.blogspot.com/2014/03/publishing-to-web-site-from-vs-2013-is.html):

VS Studio 2013 Express for Web is also known to have a bug in its UI: [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/45889822-4d75-412e-9d3c-fa06439d2ccd/open-web-site-displays-only-ftp-web-site-control-in-visual-studio-2013-express-for-web?forum=vssetup#d3718b2d-0627-4e2a-8871-5f8173463863)

If some items are missing in the UI, perhaps the application is corrupted and you may need to reinstall.