# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, html, css, relative-path

I can't solve my link problem. Could you help on to this to link CSS and JS File?

CSS:

```
<link  href="../Jquery/jquery.multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link  href="../Jquery/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link  href="../Jquery/prettify.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

JS:

```
<script  src="../Jquery/jquery.multiselect.js"></script>
<script  src="../Jquery/prettify.js"></script>
```

Error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:8080/RetailSmart/jsp/Jquery/jquery.multiselect.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:8080/RetailSmart/jsp/Jquery/style.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:8080/RetailSmart/jsp/Jquery/prettify.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:8080/RetailSmart/jsp/Jquery/jquery.multiselect.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:8080/RetailSmart/jsp/Jquery/prettify.js
```

Refer this link Directory structure.

[image]

Comment: its working now according to his answer @Geddemet

Comment: Then please accept his answer with the green checkbox by the voting arrows.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96032/magento-2-installation-issue-404-error-while-trying-to-load-admin-page i refer you to check this issue here

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Your files are not under the **jsp folder** that's why it is not found.
You have to go back again 1 folder
Try this:

```js
<script src="../../Jquery/prettify.js"></script>
```

Comment: I was facing the same issue with a font. It works fine now . :)

Comment: I was getting an error - "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)". This solution worked for me.

Comment: My path is correct but it still gives me this error: undefined:1 GET http://localhost/e-commerce/undefined 404 (Not Found)

Comment: my files were in a completely other folder lol, and this answer helped me realize that

Answer (score 19):

Note the failing URL:

```
Failed ... http://localhost:8080/RetailSmart/jsp/Jquery/jquery.multiselect.css
```

Now examine one of your links:

```
<link href="../Jquery/jquery.multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

The "../" is shorthand for "The containing directory", or "Up one directory".  This is a **relative** URL.  At a guess, you have a file in /jsp/<somefolder>/ which contains the <link /> and <style /> elements.

I recommend using an **absolute** URL:

```
<link href="/RetailSmart/Jquery/jquery.multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

The reason for using an absolute url is that I'm guessing the links are contained in some common file.  If you attempt to correct your relative pathing by adding a second "../", you may break any files contained in /jsp.

Answer (score 7):

If you have resource with woff extension and getting error then add following code in your web.config application will help to fix.

```
<system.webServer>
<staticContent>
   <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
</staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

For Resources like JavaScript or CSS not found then provide the path of adding link or script in following way

```
<link ref="@(Url.Content("path of css"))" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="@(Url.Content("path of js"))" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I'm using Asp.net I'v edited my web.config as mentioned, then I started getting error 500

Comment: Error status 500 is related to resource not found... please check which resources are you mission....

Comment: You can also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error

Comment: I get the error for the font file. not for the whole page

Answer (score 5):

Add this to your Configuration file. Then put all your resources(eg. img,css,js etc) into the src > main > webapp > resources       directory.

```
public class Config extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
   @Override
   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {  
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
   }
}
```

After this, you can access your resources like this.

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/assets/css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 4):

If your URL is:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/binding/
```

Update the below property in the index.html

```
<base href="/binding/">
```

In short, you need to check the locations of the files.

Answer (score 3):

Add this below code(`<handler>`) on your web.config within `<system.webServer>`:

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are loading js from same folder just use forward slash

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

replace by

```
<script src="/bundle.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have added  `app.UseStaticFiles();` this code in my startup.cs than it is fixed

Answer (score 1):

I was having this exact issue and this was because I was returning images from a server into component that is 1 step down the path. This what I mean. See file arrangement

```
*projectfolder/phpfiles/component.php*
```

Now my images folder was located here *projectfolder/images/*

Now I fixed it by adding *../* so that it could skip 1 step backwards

Goodluck

Answer (score 0):

Please note , you might need to disable adblocks if necessary.
Drag and drop off script path in visual studio doesn't work if you are using HTML pages but it does work for mvc ,asp.netwebforms.
I figured this after one hour

Answer (score 0):

Please install App Script for Ionic 3 Solution

```
npm i -D -E @ionic/app-scripts
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the error was the files under js folder not included in the project this solve my issue :

1- In the solution explorer toolbar click Show All Files.

2- open js folder and select all files under the folder

3- right click then select include In Project

4- Save and build your application then its working correct and load .css and .js files

Answer (score 0):

```
// To fix this issue, please add the below changes to src/index.html
For example : ( add project name or project root path ) 
<base href="/enter_project_folder_name/">
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For me the Error was simply, that the font file name had whitespaces:
*TT Interphases Pro Mono Trial Italic.tt*
Change it to
*TT_Interphases_Pro_Mono_Trial_Italic.ttf*