# Idea loose ramda.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea, ramda.js

[image]It was nice code, that do, what it have to do. Then  I try to export it.  Than "make project" and after that it dosnt work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Users/elenabugercuk/IdeaProjects/proff29/node_modules/ramda/dist/ramda.js"></script>



</head>

<body>
<script>
    google.load("feeds", "1");
    var R = require("ramda");

</script>
```

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (HTTP/1.1 404) http://localhost:8080/Users/elenabugercuk/IdeaProjects/proff29/node_modules/ramda/dist/ramda.js

The file ramda.js is present in specified dir. 
 I try to solve like this [Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317206/failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-404-not-found)
But without result.

Can you give me advice?

Comment: Are you sure the file is there, in your server folder? It seems you are confusing local paths in your OS with the absolute/relative path to your server... Also what is `require` in this context? Are you using Browerify or something?

Comment: Yes. File is present by path.

Comment: i dont use Browserify. The problem is before "require"

Comment: What is "make project"? How are you serving your app?

Comment: i dont shure its was a reason. Just discribe evrething i did. 
"make project" - the icon in right top corner of the image. Just on left from "indexRSS.jsp(5)"

Comment: Can you try this by manually building a small version of your app?  It does look as though you might be trying to combine client-side and server-side coding styles.