# The server responded with a status of 404 using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cocos2d-js

I tried to create a simple AJAX call to php script.

request.js

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', './assets/script/api/sample.php');

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status <= 207)) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
}

xhr.send();
```

sample.php

```
<?php echo "Hello World"; ?>
```

Error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) (localhost:7456/assets/script/api/sample.php)

Comment: is `/assets/script/api/sample.php` the correct path to sample.php?

Comment: Hi @Krissy please check sample.php path and file name

Comment: it is a correct path.

Comment: what do you get if you put `http://localhost:7456/assets/script/api/sample.php` in your browser address

Comment: Could you have a rewrite rule on the server that's changing the path? Check the access log.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen that error come from an AJAX request. I have seen it come from `<script>` and `<link>` tags with incorrect URLs (see [Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317206/failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-404-not-found)). Are you absolutely sure the code in your question is producing this error?

Comment: this .js file is for the game project I am making from cocos2d-js. I tried to open the sample.php to the browser and returns 404 error. my possible guess is that my php was placed somewhere on the server after building.

Answer (score 0):

Recently fixed this problem. The php file should be placed on the build folder.