# 500 - Internal server error with godaddy

Tags: asp.net

after i finished uploading my website, I found this error when I try to preview my website
how can I solve this error? I try to add this code

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
</system.web> 
</configuration>
```

in web.config
to get details about the error but the error message still the same!!!
how can I solve it?

Comment: Could you maybe dump the entire error log - if there may be a trace - so we can see what the issue may be?

Comment: please add snapshot of error

Comment: possible duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error

Answer (score 0):

One of the many cause of this error on Godaddy hosting is the framework version.

In this case, just change the .Net version

Go to `ASP.Net setting` and then click `Change Version`. Now, here you may downgrade the version to 2.0 .

This simple change in this case will work like a magic.

If your problem is still not resolved, please reply.