# Hosting IIS8 ASP.Net site

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an ASP.Net website running on Server 2012, IIS 8. I am getting a generic, not server provided 404 message. I have the ports forwarding through the router, I have my site and IP setup in the Hosts file, and have the site bindings configured to the proper address and port. The site works fine on the local machine browsing the url (not just localmachine), but nothing outside the server, even other machines on the network can get to the site.

Any suggestions as to what I should do next?

Comment: Start by finding the error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error/5385884#5385884

Comment: Custom errors are on. The 404 looks like a generic one from the client browser not finding the server. On an iPhone I am getting the server stopped responding. It looks like the client isn't getting to the server, and if they are, not to the site itself. EDIT: I just turned the firewall completely off and same response.

Comment: Also, my router is forwarding port 80 to the server. It worked before, but it isn't now and I can't figure out why.