# 500 - Internal server error after deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, iis

I am making an MVC 4 application in VS 2013 using .NET 4.5.

The beginnings of my application are running fine locally, however after they are deployed, whenever I try to reach the URL I get :

**500 - Internal server error**

How do I find out what this error is caused by? I have tried turning off the friendly error messages in IE. Also I have tried adding customErrors mode="Off" to the main web.config both of which have not worked.

Comment: errors of that sort are generally kept in a system log somewhere, since they can potentially leak sensitive internal data. check the server's logs, or maybe the windows event log.

Comment: try deploying it on your systems IIS, if you have access to the database try connecting to the DB from your application by changing the connection string

Comment: Please take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error