# 500 (Internal Server Error) for sending post request to aspx page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I want to send the json file from client side to server side using ajax, the json file is the "lists". But I'm getting 500(Internal server error). How to solve this problem...

This is the jquery....

```
        $("#save").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/external/ajax.aspx/OnSubmit",
                data: lists,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("We returned: " + result);
                }
            });
        });
```

This is the aspx page containing the web method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
public partial class iyesqueries_ajax : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
[WebMethod]
public static string OnSubmit(string json)
{
    return "hi";
}
}
```

Please help me with this....

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting ?

Comment: First locate the error, following this instructions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error/5385884#5385884

Comment: what is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should **stringify** the list

```
var response = { "list": lists };

data: JSON.stringify(response),

AND 

public static string OnSubmit(list<yourClazName> list)
```