# Redux framework causing site to give 500 internal server error

Tags: wordpress, internal-server-error, redux-framework

The medical theme I am using on my website dentavacation.com makes use of the plugin Redux framework. Since I was facing a lot of 500 interval server errors intermittently, I called up my hosting provider. As per them, this had got to do with a plugin and they suggested I deactivate all the plugins and then activate them one by one to find the trouble giver. I did the same and could figure the plugin Redux Framework either increases the loading time of my home page or makes it give a 500 internal server error. What do I do about this as this plugin has a major role to play in the look and feel of the home page.

PS. I have the same theme and plugins running seamlessly on other websites too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deploying website: 500 - Internal server error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error)

Comment: @kmlnvm - definitely NOT a duplicate of the question you linked.

Answer (score 0):

Lead dev of Redux here. I'd suggest you do the following:

1. Delete the version of Redux you have installed and install via the plugin installer within WordPress (NOT FTP), the version of Redux had on WordPress.org.
2. If that doesn't work, as your host to check your file permissions.

Best of luck!

Comment: I was hoping this worked but it did not.  I get the following error `[13-Nov-2015 17:29:31 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Evolve_Redux_Customizer_Section' not found in /home2/myuserpath/public_html/wp-content/plugins/redux-framework/ReduxCore/inc/extensions/customizer/extension_customizer.php on line 588`.  (side note) Before you try this be sure to change to a theme that is NOT DEPENDANT on Redux Framework!  Otherwise, like me you will have a site that will not load (even the wp-admin).  If you have already done this ftp to the web server and rename the theme folder until you reinstall redux.

Comment: Hmm, that's an evolve thing. We don't have an Evolve_Redux_Customizer_Section.

Comment: I rolled back the theme to a previous version and confirmed it was indeed the evolve theme.  :/  sorry for hijacking the thread, but someone may find the side note helpful.  ;)