# Cannot see detailed errors of Internal Server 500 errors

Tags: .net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I am running a Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.1 application in IIS7.5 and I am getting the generic:

> 500 - Internal server error.
>
> There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

I have tried the following to get more detail on the actual error but so far, face palming:

- Set 
  `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;`
- Added `<system.webserver>
  <httperrors existingresponse="PassThrough"/>
  </system.webserver>`
- Checked windows event log for any unhandled exceptions, but none
- Added an `ExceptionLogger`, but nothing appears in log file:

  ```
  public class Log4NetExceptionLogger : ExceptionLogger
  {
     private readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Log4NetExceptionLogger));

     public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
     {
        _log.Error("An unhandled exception occurred.", context.Exception);
        base.Log(context);
     }
  }
  ```
- Added

  `<configuration>
     <system.webServer>
      <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
      <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="Off"/>
      <compilation debug="true"/>
    </system.web>
  </configuration>`
- Browsed locally and get "This page can't be displayed" in IE, with a binding that was NOT localhost

I see the 500 responses in the IIS logs, just no detail to the error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deploying website: 500 - Internal server error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a binding to localhost for your website and navigate to http://localhost within a web browser on your server.

Since the request is coming from localhost, IIS will show you the error details in the browser.

Not a great solution, but the fastest that I've found so far.

Comment: Great, thanks dude, did the localhost binding and found the actual error