# Switch to local database MVC application

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

Since I've got a local copy of my database server, I would like to change the server IP address in hosts file and point it to the local database. Is there any way of doing this without having to amend any piece of code?

Comment: change `connection string` based on where you want to connect. use `web.debug.config` to do that

Comment: That's what the config is for, just change your connection string. If you _really_ want to fake a host, what have you tried? Editing your hosts file is documented very thoroughly on the web.

Comment: @entre Is there any possibility of doing this without amending the code itself?

Comment: @CodeCaster I've tried to point my database server to the local host IP and it didn't work.

Comment: With "it didn't work" we can't do much.

Comment: its not code change.. its config

Comment: @entre I see, should I modify only the config file without messing with the hosts?

Comment: @CodeCaster Sorry, you are right, I've got an error : HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error

Comment: exactly.. only config, without messing with hosts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the connection string in your web.config.debug file

You can change it using the xdt:Transforms
Like this:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="name" connectionString="local connection string here" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you've coded the application.  If you have created the connection string inside the application , they you would need to change code . Or if the settings are in a config file . editing the config file should be enough.

If you have changed the host entry , check if the IP itself is accessible and the specific port is open or not.

Also do you need to authenticate differently ?  Posting the stack trace might be helpful.