# Internal Server Error when trying to receive POST data from backend; ASP.NET MVC with AngularJS

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

the GetTeams backend successfully is returning a list.. but I can't even console.log the data nor do anything.  If i have GetTeams return:

```
return Json("testing", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

it works fine though.  I can't understand what's going on here and why this doesn't work.  Can someone help me?  Thanks

ASP.NET MVC

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetTeams(int leagueId)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var sdb = new SoccerDataEntities())
            {
                var teamList = (from teams in sdb.footballTeams
                                orderby teams.name ascending
                                where teams.league_id == leagueId
                                select teams).ToList();

                return Json(teamList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
        }
    }
```

Angular Controller

```
HeadlinesFactory.getTeamsFromLeague(league.LeagueId)
        .success(function (data) {                
            console.log(data);
        });
```

EDIT:

Classes

```
public class footballTeam
{
    public footballTeam();

    public string coach { get; set; }
    public virtual footballLeague footballLeague { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int league_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int season_id { get; set; }
    public int team_id { get; set; }
    public string TeamDetails { get; set; }
}

public class footballLeague
{
    public footballLeague();

    public virtual ICollection<footballFeedUpdate> footballFeedUpdates { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<footballPlayer> footballPlayers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<footballPromotionRelegation> footballPromotionRelegations { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<footballTeam> footballTeams { get; set; }
    public bool? groups { get; set; }
    public int league_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

SQL Columns

- id
- team_id
- league_id
- season_id
- name
- coach
- TeamDetails

Comment: Just as a test, could you remove the using statement. This kind of thing is almost always having to do with the queryable being disposed. Albeit, you're resolving with a .ToList() and if that wasn't the case, you'd think you'd at least get an error.

Comment: As an additional test, could you also just return a collection of teams.name in your select to see if it's a property on teams that's not able to be serialized.

Comment: @JoshuaBelden okay let me try right now

Comment: @JoshuaBelden ah, when I change to "select teams.name" it works, but I do need the full object.. how can I go about doing that?

Comment: side note, `.success` is depreciated, and you should use `.then` instead, wherever possible

Comment: @Claies ah ty i will look into that

Comment: back to your original issue, it sounds like there is some property in the `teams` class that can't be serialized properly; can you show what the class definition looks like?

Comment: You need to share the [full details for the Internal Server Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error). This will help you narrow down what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: @Claies updated the OP with the classes and also the columns in the SQL table

Comment: For what it's worth, I have had nothing but problems and frustration from trying to serialize and return data entities diurectly. I'd highly recommend recommend you look at serializing viewmodels or anonymous objects to prevent the serialization logic from traversing your entire entities and all their associated references, collections and potentially lazy loaded properties.

Comment: this looks like you have `teams` which refer to `footballLeague` which in turn refers back to `teams`.  I suspect the serializer is having a hard time with the circular reference here.  Do you have an initializer in your app to deal with circular references?

Comment: @Jasen hm tried the suggestions from the link you posted but i don't see it giving me more details.. i'll spend more time to look more into that later in the work day.

Comment: @NickAlbrecht fml me too man............ ty for the suggestions to look into

Comment: take a look at this article: http://johnnycode.com/2012/04/10/serializing-circular-references-with-json-net-and-entity-framework/

Comment: @Claies ah maybe that's it, i'm going to try disregarding that property (thankfully i dont' need that one specifically) and see what happens..

Comment: I still recommend giving that linked article a read, even though you did find a solution to the current issue.  That article discusses a couple changes that can enforce a global policy for serialization which may help deal with many issues, not just this specific one.

Comment: @Claies i definitely will.  i have it bookmarked!  i just have a deadline right now.. so can't spend too much time on it at this very moment.. i love understanding WHY though and not just a quick solution, so i very much appreciate the knowledge.  ty again!

Comment: The accepted answer is using a projection into an anonymous object so that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a projection to return only the data you need and to also ensure you're not returning any Linq types from the query.

```
        var teamList = (from teams in sdb.footballTeams
            orderby teams.name ascending
            where teams.league_id == leagueId
            select new
            {
             id = teams.id,
             team_id = teams.team_id,
             league_id = teams.league_id,
             season_id = teams.season_id,
             name = teams.name,
             coach = teams.coach,
             TeamDetails = teams.TeamDetails
            }).ToList();

        return Json(teamList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```