# mvc application shows 500 internal server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have developed one mvc 4 application and hosted on server and its working fine.but now i want to host this application on  another `plesk server 12.0.18` , but application shows following error

> 500 internal server error.there is a problem with the resource you are
>   looking for,and it can not be displayed.

I have set custom error mode 'off' but still same error is occurring. 
I have two connection strings. If i specify connection string of another server then application is working fine and if i specify connection string of plesk database then error occurs again.
So its about connection string.so i think entity framework not connecting to plesk database so is it about permission or what?

But i can connect with that database from web application they have provided by using my little admin for sql server.but not with connection string from application.

connection string 1 : home page is displayed and all events in global.ascx get called.like application_start , session_start etc.

connection string 2 : No events from global.ascx called.Gives 500 error

:

Comment: You should update your web config to turn off customErrors so that it can show you the detailed error information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deploying website: 500 - Internal server error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error)

Comment: no my problem is different.If i change database connection string then application is working fine.And if i give connection string of plesk server then it showing 500 error.Even Application start event or session start event is not calling.