# ASP.NET5 500 Error when using the repository pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

**Edit 3:** I don't know what I did to fix this, but my problem went away. I think the most important things I found, and to take away if you have this issue is that in ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 we have to add middleware for almost everything, including the developer error pages using `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();`... after that I realized that the stack trace might be referring to other classes referenced from within the controller such as the repository and the context object, in my case. I messed with them a bit but I don't remember changing anything drastic. I think I may have had a typo in the constructor of my repository class.

I'm getting a 500 Internal Server Error with the controller, but it displays the static json data without the constructor just fine. I suspect there is something going wrong with the built-in dependency injection but I can't figure it out as I'm not getting any errors or warnings during build.

Edit: I see absolutely *nothing* in browser when navigationg to `http://localhost:5000/api/blogpost/`. Just a blank page. No Error. No nothing. Using Postman to send the HTTP request, I get error code 500. Again, by commenting out the constructor I see `{"name":"Cameron"}`, and get code 200 OK in both browser and Postman. There are no exceptions within VS, and there are no errors in the Output console either.

Edit 2: I found the middleware `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();` and it produces `MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.` - If I make a parameterless constructor, it produces: `InvalidOperationException: Multiple constructors accepting all given argument types have been found in type 'MyApp.Controllers.BlogPostController'. There should only be one applicable constructor.` - It seems like something whacky is going on with ASP.NET5's dep injection?

Here's my controller:

```
using MyApp.Data.Repository;
using MyApp.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using System;

    namespace MyApp.Controllers
    {
        [Route("api/[controller]")]
        public class BlogPostController : Controller
        {
            // If I comment out this var and the constructor this works.
            private IBlogPostRepository _repository;

            // If I leave them here, I get a 500 Internal Server Error.
            // If I set a breakpoint here, it never fires.
            // If I create a constructor that takes zero args, it never fires.
            // I do not get any errors.
            public BlogPostController(IBlogPostRepository repository)
            {
                _repository = repository;
            }

            [HttpGet]
            public JsonResult Get()
            {
                return Json(new { name = "Cameron" });
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is Startup.cs ConfigureServices:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // MVC 6
    services.AddMvc();

    // EntityFramework 7
    services.AddEntityFramework()
        .AddSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
        {
            // Will use the last Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString
            // that was loaded from the config files in the constructor.
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]);
        });

    // Injections
    services.AddTransient<AppDbContextSeedData>();
    services.AddScoped<IBlogPostRepository, BlogPostRepository>();
}
```

Comment: What is the type of the exception? and what message?

Comment: @JoelRamosMichaliszen, there is no exception. No error of any kind. Even when I load it in my browser, I see nothing. I see the 500 internal server error when trying to load from Postman.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error

Comment: @CodeCaster: thanks for the reference to enable detailed errors, but there was no change. I get no exceptions, no errors of any kind, except for the code 500 from Postman.

Comment: What _do_  you see? Are you running IE and is the option "Show friendly HTTP messages" enabled by any chance?

Comment: @CodeCaster I edited my original response as that might clarify to everyone that I really do see absolutely nothing. Also, I'm running Chrome, Firefox and Postman HTTP request sender.

Comment: some additional info about the error message would be useful, either via the inspector - see the HTTP response part from the browsers inspector, https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/resource-loading , or maybe there's an error message while debugging?

Comment: we know the http500 response has nothing visible on screen, but you can usually dig in a bit using browser tools or the debugger to see the full response  returned

Comment: @CodeCaster @user1778606 -- Found `app.UserDeveloperExceptionPage() and posted the results in my original.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem.  My constructor was did not have a scope.  The class was public, so I added "public" before the constructor and it worked!

So, NOT WORKING:

```
public class VisualizationsController : Controller
{
VisualizationsController() {...}
}
```

And WORKING:

```
public class VisualizationsController : Controller
{
public VisualizationsController() {...}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across a situation where I was adding another controller and forgot to update the Startup.cs page.

In Startup.cs, under the ConfigureServices, try adding:

```
services.AddSingleton<ISomeRepository, SomeRepository>();
services.AddSingleton<ISomeOtherRepository, SomeOtherRepository>();
```

Assuming you're passing in ISomeOtherRepository in your new controller constructor