# Keeps getting EOF expected error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have this problem with SOAP that I can't seem to solve.
No matter what I try, then I keep getting this error:

> 500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you
>   are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

When digging further down the error code I'm told there is a EOF expected error?

Hope that some of you might be able to help me

```
<%
On Error Resume Next
Dim objXMLHTTP : set objXMLHTTP = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0")
Dim strFunction
Dim strRequest
Dim strResult
Dim strName
Dim strFirstName
Dim strLastname
Dim strAddress
Dim strZipCode
Dim strCity
Dim strTelephone
Dim strTelephone2
Dim strTelephone3
Dim strTelephone4
Dim strEmail
Dim strExtFields
Dim strStdFields
Dim CampaignID
Dim Page

Page = Request.Form("Page")
CampaignID = Request.Form("CampaignID")
StrName = Request.Form("Name")
StrTelephone = Request.Form("Phone")

strRequest = ""
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
<Body>
<InsertNewCustomer xmlns=""http://api.ivocall.dk/ivocallservice.asmx"">
<Login>Loginname</Login>
<Password>Password</Password>
<ClientID>1323</ClientID>
<IDPassword>ag4bghsitm8gatddbpt34qjndjrbsla</IDPassword>
<CampaignID>"& campaignid &"</CampaignID>
<Name>"& StrName &"</Name>
<Firstname></Firstname>
<Lastname></Lastname>
<Address></Address>
<City></City>
<ZipCode></ZipCode>
<Telephone>"& StrTelephone &"</Telephone>
<Telephone2></Telephone2>
<Telephone3></Telephone3>
<Telephone4></Telephone4>
<email></email>
<ExtFields>landingpage="& page &"</ExtFields>
<StdFields></StdFields>
<UserName></UserName>
</InsertNewCustomer>
</Body>
</Envelope>"

objXMLHTTP.open "post", "" & "http://api.ivocall.dk/ivocallservice.asmx" & "", False
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=UTF-8"
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(strRequest)
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "http://www.ivocall.dk/ivocallservice/InsertNewCustomer"

'send the request and capture the result
Call objXMLHTTP.send(strRequest)
strResult = objXMLHTTP.responseText

'display the XML
response.write strResult
response.write strRequest 

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Response.Write (Err.Description)
ELSE
        Response.Write ("task done")
        Response.End
End If
%>
```

I really hope some of you can help me out her?

Comment: This is a general message. Find and show here the exactly error and where that happens. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error/5385884#5385884

Comment: The error have to do with the XML string as you have place it here...

Comment: `<InsertNewCustomer xmlns=""http://api.ivocall.dk/ivocallservice.asmx"">` Is this the problem ?

Comment: This isn't C#.  Please use correct tags.

Comment: Is this .net or classic asp? They are two different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use inline code-tags.

```
<%
```

They do not contain any imported namespaces.

Additionally, you seem to want to copying XML into strRequest, but you're not properly escaping it, plus VB.NET (which is what you're using, not C#) doesn't support multiline strings.

And why do you use

```
Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0")
```

You can use the normal WebRequest class, instead of an ActiveX-Object. And if you want to do it client-side, you need to use JavaScript (AJAX).
If you're doing a cross-domain request, you need to use CORs (and a browser supporting CORs), or you need to write a proxy that does the request for you.

Additionally, did you try adding a web-reference to your project ? 
Visual Studio will automagically download the WSDL and generate the wrapper classes. Why do you want to do it by hand ? ...

Additionally, if you want to embed code in the ASPX page, do it in a "script"-tag using `runat="server"`:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="RS" Namespace="Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer" Assembly="ReportingServicesWebServer" %>
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportViewerPage" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>

<script type="text/C#" runat="server">


    protected void SetDocumentMode()
    {
        if(System.Web.HttpContext.Current == null || System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request == null || System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser == null || System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser == null)
            // return "<null>";
            return; 

        if (!StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod, "GET"))
            // return "<notget>";
            return;

        // fu IE 11 
        if(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser == "IE" || System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser == "InternetExplorer")
        {
            if(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(System.Convert.ToString(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString), "stylesheet", System.Globalization.CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) == -1 )
            {
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(@"<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=5'>
");
                //return "<meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=5\">"; // IE5-Quirks when no custom stylesheet (=not in iframe)
            }
            else
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge,chrome=1'>");
                // return "<meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge,chrome=1\">"; // Switch to Standards mode when a custom stylesheet is set(=in iframe)
        }

        // return "<not ie: " + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser + ">";
        //return "";
    }
</script>

[...]
<%SetDocumentMode(); %>
```

Are you actually using ASP instead of ASP.NET ?