# *filterContext.Result = new JsonResult()* in mvc not working properly outside the server

Tags: c#, jquery

*filterContext.Result = new JsonResult()* in above code(*CustomJsonExceptionHandler*) does not work properly when I access website from outside the server.

Please see below code, function is throwing an exception. Custom attribute is being used to return the error message to ajax function

controller function

```
[HttpPost]
[CustomJsonExceptionHandler]
public ActionResult GetList(int month, int year)
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Exception");
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> List = new List<Dictionary<string,object>>()
    return Json(List, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Custom error attribute

```
public class CustomJsonExceptionHandler : HandleErrorAttribute
{

    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext != null && filterContext.Exception != null)
        {

            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult()
            {
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                Data = new
                {
                    errorMessage = filterContext.Exception.Message
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Please see below code of jquery ajax function

```
$.fn.GetData = function (month, year) {
    var data = null;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/HomeController/GetList',
        data: { month: month, year: year },
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        success: function (Listdata) {
            data = Listdata;
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            var jsonerror = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText)
            alert(jsonerror.errorMessage)
        }
    });
    return data;
}
```

Please Help !!

Comment: What does the exception message say?

Comment: In jQuery function xhr.responseText does not come as expected. Hence $.parseJSON throwing an error. Hope that make sense

Comment: It does but I don't think anyone can help you unless you tell us exactly what the error says. Just saying "it throws an error" doesn't give us any clues

Comment: Hi Dyson, In CustomJsonExceptionHandler class OnException function returns a exception in Json format ({"errorMessage" : "Exception"}). jQuery function GetData accepts this error in error property. This works fine when I access website in localhost. But not working outside the localhost. xhr.responseText gives some weird text please see text in next comment

Comment: ([+]  xhr.responseText "
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">
\r\n
<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\r\n
<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\"/>\r\n
<title>500 - Internal server error.</title>\r\n
<style type=\"text/css\">\r\n
<!--\r\nbody
{
margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;
}\r\n
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} \r\nh1
{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}\r\nh2

Comment: serif;color:#FFF;\r\nbackground-color:#555555;}\r\n#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}\r\n.content-container
{
background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}\r\n-->\r\n</style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n<div id=\"header\"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>\r\n<div id=\"content\">\r\n <div class=\"content-container\"><fieldset>\r\n  <h2>500 - Internal server error.</h2>\r\n  <h3>There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.</h3>\r\n </fieldset></div>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n" String

Comment: Ok so that's just the standard HTTP 500 server error. It does not tell you what is going wrong internally. You need to debug on the server side, or log the exception into the Windows event log, and then you should see what the real error is inside the server

Comment: I got the solution please find answer in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error

Comment: That link tells you a way to get your underlying error message, yes. Did you also fix the problem that was causing the error? If so, you should post the solution here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi issue is resolved I have added following to web.config

```html
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

please see below link for reference

[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error)