# Get handler is not called

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-applications

In an asp.net code I'm working on, it has the following code in controller class to handle GET request.

```
public class NotificationsController : ApiController
{
   public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get([FromUri]string message)
   {
      .....
```

In webapiconfig file, the route is mapped as

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

When I make GET request, the GET handler isn't even called. What am I missing here?

EDIT :

My GET request looks like : domain name here /api/notifications?message="hello"

Comment: At first glance, there's nothing wrong with this code. What does your GET request look like, exactly? Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: I just updated my post. I didn't post the GET request handler function body since it's not even get called so it isn't relevant.

Comment: So what does happen when you issue that request?

Comment: Just 500 internal server error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error