# "500 - Internal server error." on IIS app 4.0

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I made a simple asp.net web application that does nothing. It works using .net framework 2.0 (as do all the other applications on the server), but when I change it to .net framework 4.0 I get a "500 - Internal server error".

To change to 4.0, I compiled with .Net Framework 4.5.2 (also tried 4.0), and I changed the application pool in IIS to ASP 4.0 integrated.

I set web.config to display errors, but it's still only the vague error message above. I can see no errors or warnings in the system logs. I did register .net framework v4.0.30319.

What can cause this?

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off">
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm"/>
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm"/>
    </customErrors>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Check eventlog for some information. Maybe there will be some error like .net app pool crash.

Comment: There's nothing in the event log.

Comment: Did you look in eventlog in Windows logs/Application?

Comment: Yes. Nothing is there.

Comment: Tried re-booting the web server?

Comment: also check the settings in your app config file

Comment: I did -- removed all unnecessary settings with no change.

Comment: @xpda browse website from IIS it will show complete error.

Comment: @Leopard How do you "browse website from IIS"?

Comment: @xpda go to IIS select your website. Right click and select Manage Website and then click Browse.

Comment: The only thing that comes up is "Server Error, 500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed."

Comment: This is a generic error message, you need to find the details - Look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error/5385884#5385884

Comment: have you tried debugging?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you  did not register .NET 4.0 installation **Properly**. you need to run in the `cmd` with following parameters `"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i"`

Steps to Install this Command

1.Now you need to start command prompt by typing cmd at the Run command and then   execute the command prompt with Administrator rights by right clicking and  choosing Run as administrator from the context menu.

2.Then on the command prompt you need to navigate to the Directory that has the     `aspnet_regiis.exe` file for that you need to type
 `CD C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\`
And then you need to type the following command and hit enter to register ASP.Net with IIS.
`aspnet_regiis -i`

Comment: @xpda can you post your webconfig .

Comment: @xpda i'm assuming your server is installed with the framework 4.5 + right?

Comment: Yes, it is installed and registered.

Comment: @xpda i know you might checked everywhere but can you please refer this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/311766#toc) with title  **When IIS 4.0 runs in its own memory space**

Answer (score 2):

Enable and see **detailed errors** of your web messages whit it you can locate real issue. If you can run the browser on the server, you get details on the error, because the server recognizes that you are local and shows it to you. **Event Viewer**,  also show the details of your error. Try it with **debug="true"**.

```
<configuration>
        <system.webServer>
            <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
            <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
        </system.webServer>
        <system.web>
            <customErrors mode="Off"/>
            <compilation debug="true"/>
        </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks, but there was no change with these.

Comment: @xpda IIS show details to the error by default when you access from the local machine, do you have access to the desktop of the server where IIS is installed? In any case, based on everything you have reviewed so far I'm pretty sure the problem is related to file access permissions.

Comment: Yes, I have access.