# Run mvc application on local IIS get 500 error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, deployment, iis-10

I want to run my mvc application on local IIS and use [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rickandy/2011/04/22/test-your-asp-net-mvc-or-webforms-application-on-iis-7-in-30-seconds/) for do that, but when I run my project in borwser I have got error 500.19

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>   The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

All of answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error) didn't resolve my problem. I'm using visual studio 2015 update 3 and IIS 10.

What's the problem?

Comment: This error suggests the web.config is invalid. do a debug build and you should see a lot more info on the page.

Comment: what 'debug build` means?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/507Vao2l.png this shows what debug build is

Comment: Oh,I knew that :) but when I build in debug mode I don't have any error.

Comment: then check the `Web.Release.config`, it may be that a transform is applying somewhere causing this issue.

Comment: Why should I check `Web.Release.config`? I am in debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

Installing IIS Features on Windows 8 and Windows 10
The following procedure describes how to install IIS and the required features for the Microsoft Dynamics NAV Web client on Windows 8 and Windows 10.

To install IIS features on Windows 8 and Windows 10
On the Start page, choose Control Panel, and then choose Programs.

Under Programs and Features, choose Turn Windows features on or off.

The Windows features dialog box appears.

Expand the root-level item .NET Framework 4.5 Advanced Services (for Windows 8) or .NET Framework 4.6 Advanced Services (for Windows 10), and then do the following:

Select ASP.NET 4.5 (for Windows 8) or ASP.NET 4.6 (for Windows 10).

Expand WCF Services, and then select HTTP Activation.

Expand the root-level item Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 (including .NET 2.0 and 3.0), and then select Windows Communication Foundation HTTP Activation.

Note

The Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 (including .NET 2.0 and 3.0) item is only available if.NET Framework 3.50 is installed. If the item is not shown, then there is no action for this step.

Expand the root-level item Internet Information Services, expand World Wide Web Services, and then do the following:

Expand Application Development Features, and select the following features:

.NET Extensibility 3.5 (if .NET Framework 3.5 is installed)

.NET Extensibility 4.5 (for Windows 8) or .NET Extensibility 4.6 (for Windows 10)

ASP.NET 3.5 (if .NET Framework 3.5 is installed)

ASP.NET 4.5 (for Windows 8) or ASP.NET 4.6 (for Windows 10)

ISAPI Extensions

ISAPI Filters

Expand Common HTTP Features, and then select the Static Content feature.

Expand Security, and then select the following features:

Request Filtering

Windows Authentication

Under Internet Information Services, expand Web Management Tools, and then select IIS Management Console.

This is an optional step to install Internet Information Service IIS Manager. You use Internet Information Service IIS Manager to manage local and remote web servers and sites.

Choose the OK button to complete the installation.

To verify that the web server has been installed correctly, start your browser, and then type http://localhost in the address.

The default web site opens and should display an IIS 8 image.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicsnav-2016/hh167503(v=nav.90)#Win8)

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net 4 not install use this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx