# 500 - Internal server error when deploying to IIS

Tags: mysql, asp.net, amazon-ec2

I am working with an ASP.NET API and MySQL connection. Everything is fine in local environment. However when I deploy the app on an AWS EC2 IIS Instance and trying to access an endpoint of my application, I got as a son response 'An error has occurred.' instead of my data with a 500 error code from server.

[image]

I have connected MySQL with Entity framework. Mysql server is hosted on Amazon AWS.

I did published the project with web deploy from Visual Studio. Is there any way for database to be published wrong so this is the error?

Any help would be great. Let me know If I need to add more info.

I have seen this post without any luck: [Deploying website: 500 - Internal server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error?rq=1)

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

After some tries I stepped into this:

[image]

Comment: What do the logs say?  There is nothing to go on without them.

Comment: the code at the logs is 500 19 183 74 without specifying anything more than the browser and the time of connection

Comment: Add error logging to your application. It could be as simple as sending an email within your Application_Error event. Or you could go full blown with tools like Elmah, NLog, Serilog, and/or SEQ.

Comment: Thanks for that I will

Answer (score 1):

It might be MySQL server restricts a connection from IP address which is not in  a whitelist. I know Azure SQL allows to connect from restricted range of addresses only.

Comment: Thats a good guess but I have setup the security groups in AWS of the EC2 instance to "accept" the port of the RDS.