# Getting 500 Internal server Error frequently

Tags: asp.net, iis

Recently deployed my website in server. My site contains both ASP and ASP.net pages. I'm often receiving 500 internal server error.

Not in the same page. Getting this error randomly.

This is comes randomly in random pages.

Session time out in global.asa is set as 180.
In IIS , set identity as ApplicationPool Identity.

Can anyone say why I'm getting this error very often?
FYI, in old server it worked fine. Im getting this error after migrating to new server.

Comment: Sorry, there is nowhere near enough information for us to be able to help you here. 500 internal server errors are never just that, there is always an underlying error. Turn custom errors to off in your web.config and turn off friendly errors for classic asp. Also check your server logs.

Comment: Focus on one error each time to see why is happening. To find the errors -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error/5385884#5385884