# IIS: How to add existing website as application in another website

Tags: asp.net, iis, webserver, windows-server-2012-r2, application-pool

I have 2 existing websites in IIS (v10). One of these has to be assigned as an application in the other but also be retained as a site.

Site A is web forms, Site B is MVC.

I have gone through the menus and added a 'new' application to Site A, with a new virtual directory, and pointed the physical path to the file system path of Site B. I created a new app pool with the exact same conditions as the existing app pool for Site B.

When running, I get a 500 error.

I have tried using the same app pool as Site B, and again using the same app pool as Site A. In all cases, the 500 error remains.

How is the best way to do this? Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance.

***Edited to Add:***

Forgot to mention. I have disabled custom errors in the web.config and added:

`<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" errorMode="Detailed" />`

The result on screen is:

"SiteA is currently unable to handle this request.

HTTP ERROR 500"

with no detailed or verbose error message.

Comment: consider this answer, to find the real error, and come back here to write it down -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error/5385884#5385884

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm pulling my hair out with this. I've updated my answer with more information. I did disable custom errors (forgot to add).

Comment: I noticed my mistake. by changing existingResponse="PassThrough" to auto, I was able to see the actual error detail (webc.onfig setting not recognized) and fix the problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: People use reverse proxying, instead of moving sites https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing