# 500 - Internal server error after publish on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, publish, http-status-code-500

After publishing my asp mvc app to plesk hosting I have 500 error. When I run it locally all works fine.

1. I checked my connection string. This connection string is correct and uses for another apps that hosts on that server.
2. Tried to  turn on debug and view detailed error message. 
   add such code to my web.config and turn off custom errors on server with turn on debug mode also on server (Plesk)

nothing helps.... (code with configs bellow)

3. Checked all permissions for files on server.

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Test",
                "{controller}/{action}/{GUID}/{questionNumber}",
                new { controller = "Test", action = "Index", GUID = "", questionNumber = "" }  // Parameter defaults
            );
```

How to resolve it? :(

Comment: What version of ASP.NET is the server running ? Also check if it is enabled and also check the logs. You will see the error

Comment: @Bosco. 4.7 version. In logs i just have an error 441 with message - 80 -- 
and 1381 with same message. One interesting thing than i can access to another controller (Home/About) but can not Test/NotInvited. 
I have a custom rout setting. And user by default redirects to Test/NotInvited if he do not have any key in parameter. Updated issue in description to see route settings

Comment: You’re getting a 500, but are you getting a Yellow Screen of Death? Have you tried to capture the error message and log it somewhere? Taking random guesses at routing etc isn’t going to be nearly as productive as looking at the actual error message.

Comment: So i check my code and it works fine locally without any errors but i can not get friendly error screen to debug on server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error?rq=1 

And tried this issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was in controller name. Just was renamed TestController to ExamController

Answer (score 1):

For how to find the 500 error which is related with aps.net application in the event viewer, you could refer to below steps:

1. Go to event viewer
   [image]
2. Find windows logs-> application

[image]

3. Click the filter current log in the right window and select asp.net 2.0, 4.0.
   [image]
4. Then it will show the details error content in the event viewer
   [image]
5. If you want to find the application pool related issue, you could go to the system.
   [image]
6. Click the filter current log in right window and select WAS.
   [image]
7. Then you could find the error which is related to the application pool.
   [image]