# Publish ASP.NET with Database on Windows Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, visual-studio, windows-server-2008-r2

I've created a ASP.NET MVC Web project with Visual Studio and worked with a local Database. After uploading it to my Windows Server I can't figure out how to setup the connection to its MySQL Database. I already tried nearly every solution posted here but none fit my Problem. 
I think the big problem is the connection string.

The server runs with Plesk installed if this information matters.

Comment: Can you share the details of what you tried and what issue you faced?

Comment: I've tried to put the Connection String into the web.config, with and without user property and run into a http 500.19 error with 0x80070032 IIS error. Currently I am trying the connection string in the web.config and in the web deploy configuration in VS (again) and now I'm having just an http 500 error

Comment: In order to get more insight into the problem, you'll need to configure the web app to pass the error details for the generic 500 error. Hopefully this gives you the necessary info to debug the underlying cause.

Comment: That's what I'm trying for the last 5 hours but it doesn't work

Comment: Have you seen this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error

Comment: Tried it and I just got as I got with other solutions a http 500.19 error that says that there is a mistake with this: <system.Web>

Comment: Finally solved it:

Comment: Finally solved it: I took a look at the Server Manager on my Windows Server then went to Local Server, Events and there were some Error messages. The problem was fixed by changing the application pool identity and pasting the connection string, that was made by the MSSMS (Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio), into my Visual Studio Web Deploy Profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it: I took a look at the Server Manager on my Windows Server then went to Local Server, Events and there were some Error messages. The problem was fixed by changing the application pool identity and pasting the connection string, that was made by the MSSMS (Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio), into my Visual Studio Web Deploy Profile