# 500 Internal Server Error: Unintentional Code First Exception

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, postman, http-status-code-500

So this is the full error message i receive. (see title)

[See the Postman error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyVoG.png)

I am hosting an ASP.NET Web API on Azure, as well as an Azure SQL Database.
I have connected my .edmx to the Azure Database, so it shows me the models from my hosted DB with no problems.

My huge frustration is the fact that i cannot send an API get request call whatsoever!

```
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    [System.Web.Http.Route("~/api/Admin/getTest")]
   
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public List<CARCOLOUR> getTest()
    {
        INF370KODEITEntities db = new INF370KODEITEntities();
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

        List<CARCOLOUR> testData = db.CARCOLOURs.ToList();

        return testData;
    }
```

Here is my connection string (omitted password and username for obvious reasons with '')

```
 <connectionStrings>

    <add name="INF370KODEITEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.CarwashModel.csdl|res://*/Models.CarwashModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.CarwashModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=kodeit-apidbserver-database.database.windows.net;initial catalog=KODEIT_API_db;persist security info=True;user id='';password='';MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

This call just gets a list of car colours. But each time I run the call on Postman, i get that frustrating 500 error. Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5385884/9714666)
I could luckily find a fix to show more information. But am uncertain on what to do to fix it.

Hence my question, how do i fix the "Unintended Code First" error I am receiving?

Disclaimer: I am a university student (a.k.a very novice programmer), as such i apologize in advance if I'm using the incorrect jargon, and/or am not specific/clear enough.

Comment: Have you checked that the connection string starts with metadata?

Comment: If you have access, the server logs might give you an idea why you get the...

Comment: @insane_developer Added the connection string. Thanks for reminding me! It seems i do have my string starting with metadata

Comment: @GideonBotha did you try commenting out the line that throws this exception? It would be in your DbContext class.

Comment: @insane_developer where would i find the DbContext class exactly? (i can't seem to find it. Might be looking in the wrong place)

Comment: Search the entire solution for `UnintendedCodeFirstException`. You are looking for the code that is throwing this exception. This will probably not solve your problem, though, but it's worth a shot. I never use this GUI tools, so I don't really know what else to tell you from personal experience.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I am hosting on Azure, any personal experience as to where i can find the server logs on the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out my problem

Azure did not like it that my Entity Framework models were created using the Pluralize function

- I chose this option when creating the data model: [Database first
  approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKKTa.png)
- Untick the "Pluralize or singularize generated object names"
  [Click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTarM.png)

After deleting the model, unticking pluralization, my Azure Web API could finally take requests and communicate with the Azure SQL Database