# Why I took 500 Internal Server Error when using ajax get method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, javascript-namespaces

I tring use Ajax get method but I took 500 Internal server error. I am using the following:

```
Cronom.Server.Connect = window.Cronom.Server.Connect || {};

(function (connect) {
    connect.AjajGet = function (getUrl, successFunc) {
        debugger;
        $.ajax(getUrl, {
            type: "GET",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: successFunc
        });
    };
})(Cronom.Server.Connect || {});
```

I call this function in page:

```
var list = Cronom.Server.Connect.AjajGet('/Home/GetFirstData', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Server action has a [HttpGet] attribute. Where is my mistake?

Comment: possible duplicate of [500 Internal Server Error in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996139/500-internal-server-error-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: The error is generated in the `GetFirstData()` method - probably throwing an exception somewhere, but you haven't posted that so impossible to tell

Comment: I fix this problem. My mistake is i don't use JsonRequestBehavior.
old:
<!-- language: c# -->
 return Json(new {statu = true, result}); 

new:
`code`
return Json(new {statu = true, result}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: Why are you claiming `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',`? You're making a GET request. There is no request body to describe the content-type of!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix this problem. My mistake is i don't use JsonRequestBehavior.

old:

`return Json(new {statu = true, result});`

new:

```
return Json(new {statu = true, result}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```