# Post an array using JQuery Ajax cause 500 (Internal Server Error) in MVC

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an array like this:

```
var nums=["21", "22", "23", "20", "19", "18"];
```

and this JQuery Ajax codes:

```
 $('#chk').click(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: "/BarberShop/ServiceUpdate",
        type: "Post",
        data:{ nums: nums},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
        }
    });
});
```

and Controller Action like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ServiceUpdate(string nums)
    {
      //Do something......
        return View();
    }
```

the problem is when I Post the array using ajax `nums`parameter in Controller Action is `null` and also server gives me this error:

> POST http://localhost:18322/BarberShop/ServiceUpdate 500 (Internal Server Error)
>
> n.ajaxTransport.k.cors.a.crossDomain.send @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4n.extend.ajax @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4(anonymous function) @ Barbershop:481n.event.dispatch @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3n.event.add.r.handle @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3

I have tried all answer in this links and some others:

[500-internal-server-error-on-jquery-ajax-post-asp-net-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29767718/500-internal-server-error-on-jquery-ajax-post-asp-net-mvc)

[pass-array-to-ajax-request-in-ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890524/pass-array-to-ajax-request-in-ajax)

but still have the problem.thanks

Comment: if you want it the other way where you pass a string instead of an array let me know. But, it should be simple where all you have to convert the array in javascript to a string. Anyways, let me know

Comment: also I have tried this but did not work:(string[] nums)

Comment: I imagine string[] does not work because the array length is not know ahead of time. However, the size of List<string> is dynamic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is null because on the javascript side, you are using an array.

```
var nums=["21", "22", "23", "20", "19", "18"];
```

However, on the controller side, you are expecting a string.

```
public ActionResult ServiceUpdate(string nums)
```

Change the controller side to

```
public ActionResult ServiceUpdate(List<string> nums)
```

Also, in your ajax options, make sure you set `traditional` to true

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/BarberShop/ServiceUpdate",
        type: "Post",
        data:{ nums: nums},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
        },
        traditional: true
    });
```

See [How can I post an array of string to ASP.NET MVC Controller without a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309115/how-can-i-post-an-array-of-string-to-asp-net-mvc-controller-without-a-form)

**Update**

The reason you have to use `List<string>` has to do with parameter binding. When you ajax data as an array, the back-end parameter binder will look for a similar type/structure in the parameters to bind to. This is why you cannot bind a javascript `Array` to a C# `string`.

Comment: can you tell me why like this:(List<string> nums)?